# How to give a value / get a value from a timer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a bakery simulator using windows froms in c#.
i've been told to use a timer instead of    thread.sleep but i have no idea how to implement it. What I'm trying to do is assign a random value to an int and when the timer reaches the same value as the int stop the timer and enable a button for a short amount of time.

I have no idea how to begin with this, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should just look into the api for the timer you plan on using. Most of the time they provide samples. If something isn't working as intended you can still ask questions, but if my rep was high enough i'd downvote because "This question shows no research effort". I'm pretty sure SO is intended for people to find help when they struggle, not when they're too lazy to scroll down in an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Timer Class from System.Timers. It has an event you can listen to (.Elepsed) and its constructor is called with the milliseconds as an argument. So you can go:

```
_random=new Random();
_timer=new Timer(_random.Next(1,1000000));
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_notifyUser);
_timer.Enabled = true;
```

Then your _notifyUser method will be called when time's up.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

This should help! goto the examples section of this page ...